# What's mean "?" in "awk -option {print $? }" command in linux, for example {print $1}

Tags: linux

Can someone explain what is mean "#integer" (I though this is not just number..) in awk print command in linux.

I tried to display my login history on my linux terminal,
and using the command with `awk -F ":" '{  print $1 }'`.

I thought it may be `awk -F ":" '{  print $0 }'` is same result as `awk -F ":" '{  print }'`, am I right?

Comment: Docs on [Examining Fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Examining-Fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{print $1} prints the first word of the input string.

**Example:**

Suppose that I want to terminate the process named xyz.sh
This requires 2 steps.

1. Find the process ID of the process named xyz.sh
2. kill -9 'process id'

The above 2 steps can be combined into single command using the capability of awk, like this:

```
kill  -9 `ps -e | grep xyz.sh | awk '{print $1}'`
```

In the above command, ps -e shows the process details and awk '{print $1}' extracts process id (first word of the output)

Comment: Thank you very much. Happy to know that the answer had helped.